# Using C++ constexpr can create symbol duplication?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, one-definition-rule

I'm trying to define some string literals and some constant structures.

Doing a few tests I realised that using:

```
constexpr char* name = "name";
constexpr Structure data = {1, 2, 3};
```

When compiling the different libraries I have to create the address in memory of name and data are different for each library.
This I really don't want to happen.

I did another test:

```
constexpr char* name() { return "name"; }
constexpr Structure data() { return Structure{1, 2, 3}; };
```

When compiling the different libraries this way I found (at least with GCC) that the address in memory for name and data are always the same!
Even if "data" is copied in theory.

I tried to research this behaviour, but I could not find whether this behaviour is GCC specific, or whether the reuse of the symbol is by the C++ standard.

*Edited*
What is the best way to ensure that the constexpr data is not duplicated across all libraries using it?

Comment: This is done at the linker level.  MS calls this identical COMDAT folding (common data).  Most all devs want this to happen.  You may have to resort to the heap if the linker doesn't provide a switch to turn this off.

Comment: My question is more about whether I can depend on it. Collapsing common data blocks is absolutely desirable for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, rereading the question I realised I was asking the opposite of what I actually wanted. Edited to clarify.

Comment: Got it.  Why not return by const ref to remove any thought of a copy?

Comment: I tried. I got a compilation error about returning a temporary reference. Using static gives me a compilation error about static being forbidden in constexpr.

Comment: That's due to calling the constructor locally.  I will provide a very simple answer and pass back the ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, I suspect you would want something simply as this:

```
struct Structure { int x, y, z; };
static constexpr char const* _name = "name";
static constexpr Structure _data = { 1, 2, 3 };

constexpr char const* get_name() noexcept { return _name; }
constexpr Structure const& get_data() noexcept { return _data; }
```

Then other translation units will have code similar to the following:

```
constexpr char const* n = get_name();
constexpr Structure const& d = get_data();

printf("n: %s", n);
printf("d: %d %d %d", d.x, d.y, d.z);
```

if that TU had scope to the variables, you could statically assert

```
static_assert(_name == n, "");
static_assert(&_data == &d, "");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found also another alternative, which is to embed the constexpr symbols in a class. This forces the compiler to require a symbol in a C++ file, but also gives me the right result all the times.
Instead of char* I had to use char[], but it's the only difference I needed.